# How to minimize objective function involving convolution?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, constraints

My objective function is
\begin{align} 
\underset{\mathbf{p},\mathbf{q}}{\text{min}}\hspace{4mm} (\mathbf{p*q})^T \mathbf{A}(\mathbf{p*q}) \hspace{4mm} \\ s.t \hspace{4mm}\mathbf{p^Te_p}-1=0\\\mathbf{q^Te_q}-1=0 \tag{1}
\end{align}

where $\mathbf{*}$ represents discrete-time convolution (not to be confused with circular convolution) and $\mathbf{p}\in\mathbb{R}^{n_1\times 1}$ and $\mathbf{q}\in\mathbb{R}^{n_2\times 1}$

I am defining $\mathbf{e_p}$ (*dim*: $n_1 \times 1$)

\begin{align} 
\mathbf{e_p^T} = \begin{bmatrix}
         1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}

and $\mathbf{e_q}$ (*dim*: $n_2 \times 1$)

\begin{align} 
\mathbf{e_q^T} = \begin{bmatrix}
         1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}

$n=n_1+n_2-1$. Moreover $\mathbf{A}\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ is a positive semi-definite matrix and has an eigen value decomposition $\mathbf{A}=\mathbf{V}\mathbf{\Lambda}\mathbf{V}^T$.

My question is:

1. Is this a convex optimization problem?
2. If not, then under what conditions can we get a closed form solution?

Comment: This is a monic constraint that says the only the first coordinate of $\mathbf{p}$ has to be equal to 1 i-e $p_1=1,p_i\in\mathbb{R}, i=2,3,..,n_1$

Comment: and use   $W $ the matrix of the discrete Fourier transform (possibly with zero-padding if you meant non circular convolution). so $p\ast q = W^*(P.Q)$ with $P = Wp,Q = Wq$, you get $\min_{P,Q} (W^* P.Q)^T A (W^* P.Q)$ s.t. $(e_p^T W^*)P  = 2,( e_q W^*) Q = 2$. you can incorporate those two rank-1 constraints by writing $P = M_1 P_2+c_1, Q = M_2 Q_2+c_2$ with $M$ and voila : $\min_{P_2,Q_2} ((W^* (M_1P_2+c_2. M_2Q_2+c_2))^T A (W^* (M_1P_2+c_2. M_2Q_2+c_2))$ is easy to solve by studying the subset  $\{M_1P_2+c_2. M_2Q_2+c_2\}$

Comment: I need $\mathbf{p,q}$ to be real vectors. I am not sure if involving DFT matrix will give me real vectors or not? Can you please comment on this. Secondly how are you defining $(P.Q)$?

Comment: sorry $P.Q$ is the termwise multiplication, and use the real Fourier basis instead (i.e. the matrix with cosines and sines of positive frequencies instead of complex sines of positive and negative frequencies) or the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_cosine_transform matrix

Comment: @ user1952009...I had a typo in my constraints. Just fixed it. Can you please edit your comment accordingly?

Comment: In $\min_{P_2,Q_2} ((W^* (M_1P_2+c_2. M_2Q_2+c_2))^T A (W^* (M_1P_2+c_2. M_2Q_2+c_2))$, minimization is over $P_2,Q_2$ but what about $M_1,M_2,c_1,c_2$. Where are they coming from